# Como copiar o conteúdo de uma <td> para outra <td> em uma outra linha da tabela?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Olá, estou com uma duvida.Tenho uma tabela em que cada linha tem um botão que insere uma nova linha logo abaixo, porém, gostaria de carregar algumas informações da linha acima para a linha recém criada, como posso fazer isso?

CÓDIGO HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="json2.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.alphanumeric.pack.js"></script>
        <script src="java.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="folha.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
              crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center><b><font size="5">AUTO PECAS TATETUBA LTDA - EPP</font></b></center>
        <center><b><font size="4" color="#FF0000">PEDIDO DE COTAÇÃO</font></b></center><br>
        <table id="dados">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="td_titulo"></th>
                    <th>Descrição</th>
                    <th>Fabricante</th>
                    <th>Cód. Fabricante</th>
                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                    <th>Valor Unitário</th>
                    <th>Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="pedido">3791</td>
                    <td>FITA DUPLA FACE PARA ESPELHO RETROVISOR</td>
                    <td>BRASIL LTDA</td>
                    <td>476</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="11273" class="valor"/></td>
                    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
                        <button class="add" onclick="AddTableRow(this)" type="button" 
                                data-toggle="tooltip" 
                                data-placement="top" 
                                title="Adicione uma nova peça similar">+
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="pedido">3792</td>
                <td>INTERRUPTOR LUZ DE RE</td>
                <td>AUTOMOTIVOS LTDA</td>
                <td>4489</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="493" class="valor"/></td>
                <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
                    <button class="add" onclick="AddTableRow(this)" type="button" 
                            data-toggle="tooltip" 
                            data-placement="top" 
                            title="Adicione uma nova peça similar">+
                    </button>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Gostaria de carregar somente os conteúdos da "td" descrição e "td" quantidade, que são respectivamente a coluna 2 e 5.

CÓDIDO JAVA, responsável pela inserção e remoção das linhas.

```
(function($) {  
    AddTableRow = function(btn) {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td class="descricao">&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="fab"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  class="valor"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="quantidade">&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  class="valor"/></td>';
    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<button class="remover" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">-</button>';
    cols += '</td>';

    $(newRow).append(cols);

    $(newRow).insertAfter($(btn).closest('tr'));

    return false;
    };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {    
    RemoveTableRow = function(item) {       
        var tr = $(item).closest('tr'); 

        tr.fadeOut(400, function() {          
        tr.remove();        
      });   

    return false;     
    }   
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Pra onde vc quer copiar as informações na nova linha? Nos inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer copiar as informações para a nova linha nas classes `.descricao` e `.quantidade`, basta inserir o código abaixo antes do `return false;` da função `AddTableRow`:

```
// pega o texto da 2ª coluna
var desc = $(btn).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text().trim();
// pega o texto da 5ª coluna
var qtde = $(btn).closest("tr").find("td:eq(4)").text().trim();

$(btn) // botão clicado
.closest("tr") // linha pai
.next() // próxima linha
.find(".descricao") // busca pela classe
.text(desc) // adiciona o texto
.end() // volta para o .next()
.find(".quantidade") // busca pela classe
.text(qtde); // adiciona o texto
```

Comment: Sam, não seria legal usar o mesmo find por classe (`.find(".descricao")` ) no lugar do posicional `find("td:eq(1)")`? caso a ordem das colunas mude vai continuar funcionando :)

Comment: Ricardo, não dá porque as TD's não possuem classe, aí tem que pegar pela posição.

Comment: sim isso eu entendi, estava dizendo pra sugerir que coloque as classes na tabela que já está gerada, assim com está nas novas linhas, pq fica meio estranho gerar a tabela de um jeito e depois fazer append de novas linhas com estrutura diferente ;) seria mais uma sugestão de melhoria

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção, funcionou perfeitamente.